# Reverse string in C - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have done the following function to reverse a string:

```
char* reverseString(char *original_string)
{
    int length = strlen(original_string);
    char *end_of_string = original_string + (length - 1);
    char *reversed_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);

    int count = 0;
    int top_limit = length;

    while (count < length) {
        reversed_string[count] = end_of_string[top_limit];
        top_limit--;
        count++;
    }

    return reversed_string;
}
```

The strategy that I was planning is to put a pointer at the end of the original string and go backwards copying into a new string.  I am not sure what am I doing wrong here, but when doing:

```
char* prova = "hello";
char* reversed_string;
reversed_string = reverseString(prova);
printf("%d", strlen(reversed_string));
```

It doesn't show me the correct length, and in compile time I get the following warning:

```
test.c:46: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’
```

Comment: Try to change the format specifier to `%u`

Comment: You're not null terminating reversed_string, nor are you allocating space for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type returned by `strlen` is `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. Using `%d` format to print it is in an undefined behavior. You can either use `%zu` in C99, or use `%u` and cast to `unsigned int` in C89.

```
#include <string.h>

/* C89 */ printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)strlen(reversed_string));
/* C99 */ printf("%zu\n", strlen(reversed_string));
```

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**
>   `size_t`, which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator [...].

Your algorithm is also wrong, because you use both `end_of_string` and `top_limit`. You should choose one of the two solutions.

```
#include <string.h>

char *reverseString(char *original_string)
{
    size_t length = strlen(original_string);
    char *reversed_string = malloc(length + 1);
    size_t start;
    size_t end;

    for (start = 0, end = length - 1; start < length; start++, end--)
    {
      reversed_string[start] = original_string[end];
    }

    reversed_string[start] = '\0';

    return reversed_string;
}
```

Comment: Correct, now I get that the size of the reverted string is 1, which doesn't make much sense. I can't find what am I doing wrong in my algorithm when reversing the string.

Answer (score 4):

You need one char more for the '\0', and also copy it at the end:

```
char* reverseString(char *original_string)
{
    int length = strlen(original_string);
    int top_limit = length-1;
    //char *end_of_string = original_string + top_limit;
    char *reversed_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * (1+length));

    int count = 0;

    while (count < length) {
        reversed_string[count] = original_string[top_limit];
      //reversed_string[count] = *(end_of_string--) ;
        top_limit--;
        count++;
    }
    reversed_string[count] = '\0';
    return reversed_string;
}
```

Comment: +1, but the provided source code doesn't work (see my answer).

Comment: Use of `end_of_string` looks wrong here.  The copy loop will always read beyond the end of `original_string`.  You could remove all use of `end_of_string` and just replace it with `original_string`

Comment: OK. I can full rewrite, but I tried to conserv the original. The point was to make place for the 0. Now is OK.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` returns `size_t` so you need to use a different format specifier

```
printf("%zu", strlen(reversed_string));
```

or (for strings shorter that `sizeof(int)` bytes) cast the length

```
printf("%d", (int)strlen(reversed_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%u` as format specifier instead of `%d`

```
printf("%u", strlen(reversed_string));
```